# Needing assistance with adding forms to an existing form

Tags: c#, webforms

Im new to c#, so If I were to have two forms, one being the main screen and another being a screen that I want to appear after the user clicks a button on the main page.

```
 private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if (radTeam1.Checked) 
      {
          using (Form2 Team1 = new Form2())
          {
              Team1.ShowDialog(); // Shows Form 2
          }
      }
 }
```

This is my code. I continue to receive errors and I am just stomped for some reason.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please mention the error also? I don't see any error in the mentioned code. Appreciated if code from the constructor of Form2 could be shared as well.

Comment: put your error into your question. How will anyone of us know what error you are getting?

Comment: Learn to think like a programmer. If something doesn't work, provide the details so people can understand what you did on your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
using (Form2 Team1 = new Form2())
```

is disposing your form before it is being shown on the screen.

So, change your code to:

```
if (radTeam1.Checked) 
{
    Form2 Team1 = new Form2()
    Team1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was a great help!